# Nesting IF Statements in SharePoint Calculated Column

Tags: column, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Uhh!. I have 3 statements that individually return my values. Now, I need to put these together into one formula.  Here are my statements that need combined into one calculated column. Thank you.

1st Statement,

```
Statement for Under Investigation (WORKS!)(4)
=IF(Category="Under Investigation",IF([Age in Months]=1,"Green","IF([Age in Months]=2,"Yellow",IF([Age in Months]>2,"Red","White"))))
```

2nd Statement,

```
Statement for Routine Repair (WORKS!)(8)
=IF(Category="Routine Repair",IF([Age in Months]=1,"Green", IF([Age in Months]=2,"Green”,IF([Age in Months]=3,"Green", IF([Age in Months]=4,"Green", IF([Age in Months]=5,"Yellow", IF([Age in Months]=6,"Yellow", IF([Age in Months]>6,"Red",”White”))))))))
```

3rd Statement,

```
Statement for Emerging Project (WORKS!)(14)
=IF(Category="Emerging Project",IF([Age in Months]=1,"Green", IF([Age in Months]=2,"Green”,IF([Age in Months]=3,"Green", IF([Age in Months]=4,"Green", IF([Age in Months]=5,"Green", IF([Age in Months]=6,"Green", IF([Age in Months]=7,"Green", IF([Age in Months]=8,"Green", IF([Age in Months]=9,"Green", IF([Age in Months]=10,"Green", IF([Age in Months]=11,"Yellow", IF([Age in Months]=12,"Yellow", IF([Age in Months]>12,"Red","White"))))))))))))))
```

Comment: Apply `AND` and `OR` logic in your formula to make it simple, merge into one and easy to understand. Check this, [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 1):

Please see the combined formula below.
It's not clear when the formula will result in "White" as you have greater than (example, IF([Age in Months]>2, "Red"). So, I'm assuming, when [Age in Months]=0, then it's "White"

```
=IF(OR(OR(AND(Category="Emerging Project",AND([Age in Months]<11,[Age in Months]<>0)),AND(Category="Routine Repair",AND([Age in Months]<5,[Age in Months]<>0))),AND(Category="Under Investigation",AND([Age in Months]<2,[Age in Months]<>0))),"Green",IF(OR(OR(AND(Category="Emerging Project",OR([Age in Months]=11,[Age in Months]=12)),AND(Category="Routine Repair",OR([Age in Months]=5,[Age in Months]=6))),AND(Category="Under Investigation",[Age in Months]=2)),"Yellow",IF(OR(OR(AND(Category="Emerging Project",[Age in Months]>12),AND(Category="Routine Repair",[Age in Months]>6)),AND(Category="Under Investigation",[Age in Months]>2)),"Red","White")))
```

[image]